# Node.js v0.8.6 nvm install failed, reason?

Tags: node.js, nvm

Please help!

who knows the reason that i can't install Node.Js above v0.8.6 (also can not install Node.Js v.0.7.5) using nvm 
(but successful in installing Node.Js v0.6.13)

Thanks a lot in advance!

the info is below:

CentOS 5.4

```
# python --version
Python 2.7.3

# nvm install v0.8.6
Additional options while compiling: 
######################################################################## 100.0%
  File "./configure", line 325
    o['default_configuration'] = 'Debug' if options.debug else 'Release'
                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
nvm: install v0.8.6 failed!
```

Comment: Are you still having this issue? If not, how did you solve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exactly the same problem when my python version was 2.4. But after I upgraded my python to 2.7.1, it works. But your python version seems OK.